# itextpdf issues with converting html to pdf

Tags: c#, html, itext, itext7

I am trying the following code

```csharp
using (FileStream htmlSource = File.Open(@"c:\dev\fleh.html", FileMode.Open))
using (FileStream pdfDest = File.Open(@"c:\dev\newout2.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlSource, pdfDest, converterProperties);
}
```

which is basicly copied from https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/convert-html-css-to-pdf-pdfhtml

when I try a simple Hello world html it works like a charm.
When I try my [29kb email template rendered html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/126vrwj6i2jORRMUzdwvs7NID74Elvry9/view?usp=sharing) it gives a very cryptic error.

[image: Nullable object must have a value.]

With this stack trace:

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_NoValue()
at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
at iText.Layout.Renderer.TextRenderer.GetYLine()
at iText.Layout.Renderer.TextRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.ParagraphRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.ParagraphRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.DrawChildren(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Draw(DrawContext drawContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.DocumentRenderer.FlushSingleRenderer(IRenderer resultRenderer)
at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.Layout.HtmlDocumentRenderer.FlushSingleRenderer(IRenderer resultRenderer)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.RootRenderer.AddChild(IRenderer renderer)
at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.Layout.HtmlDocumentRenderer.ProcessWaitingElement()
at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.Layout.HtmlDocumentRenderer.Close()
at iText.Layout.Document.Close()
at iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(Stream htmlStream, PdfDocument pdfDocument, ConverterProperties converterProperties)
at iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(Stream htmlStream, PdfWriter pdfWriter, ConverterProperties converterProperties)
at iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(Stream htmlStream, Stream pdfStream, ConverterProperties converterProperties)
at UnitTests.PDF.PDFtest.testHtml2Pdf() in C:\dev\fjarhagsadstodNytt\src\api\Fjarhagsadstod\UnitTests\PDF\PDFtest.cs:line 18
```

This is line 18 :

```csharp
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileStream(@"c:\dev\htmilð.html",FileMode.Open), new FileStream(@"c:\dev\output2.pdf",FileMode.OpenOrCreate), converterProperties);
```

This error basically leads me nowhere, and this html works just fine in any browser.
Any ideas ?

Regards,
Emil

Comment: Please share the stack trace of the error. And also a html as small as possible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Even the stacktrace is to large to add here. Can I add files somehow ?

Comment: You can use a file sharing platform of your choice (please don't use one that drowns a downloader in ads), e.g. public google drive or dropbox shares, and post the link here.

Comment: here are the links to the files https://drive.google.com/file/d/126vrwj6i2jORRMUzdwvs7NID74Elvry9/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P_ykvCuxQsn5eMo8z4tEXBGXweu4aOKP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, the stack trace does fit into the question, I edited it in there.

Comment: As an aside, when writing PDFs, `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` is almost always wrong, you usually want `FileMode.Create` which *is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate.* ([MS docs on FileMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=net-6.0)) Oh, I see, the iText example also uses `OpenOrCreate`...